# manage rds connected to auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elb

My current setup on AWS includes a **Classic Load Balancer ELB** attached to an **Auto Scaling group** where **EC2** server resides. All in a public subnet. I have also a **MySQL RDS** set up in a private subnet and connected to the public subnet.

Currently, i use an **ssh tunnel** and **Sequal pro** locally to manage the RDS and check the table records. I've used this tutorial http://www.frontcoded.com/amazon-rds-with-sequel-pro.html .

My problem is i want another way to manage my RDS where i can connect remotely, without the need of referring to the running EC2 instances.

Is there a way to connect the RDS to the ELB? or maybe manage the RDS without referring to an EC2? or any other suggestion?

I'm new to AWS and would appreciate  your help :)

Comment: To be able to access RDS remotely you need to make your instance publicly accessible i.e. set it up in a public subnet OR setup a new EC2 bastion host to connect to your private RDS instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people who may face the same issue in the future, this is how I've solved it:

**1. I have installed phpMyAdmin using AWS Documentation** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

I'm running a Laravel application on my EC2 stored in `"/var/www/html"`, so I've installed phpMyAdmin in `"/var/www"`.

**2. Edited Apache configuration file to include phpMyAdmin**, which is (`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` based on server type)

I've added the following `Alias /phpMyAdmin /var/www/phpMyAdmin`. At this point, i was able to access phpMyAdmin and my application without any issues.

**3. Lastly, phpMyAdmin allows for local access only by default, so I've configured it for remote access to RDS** with the help of this tutorial https://medium.com/coding-cheatsheet/how-to-using-phpmyadmin-to-administer-amazon-rds-e2019aec1251

**NOTE:** You might need to rename `config.sample.inc.php` to `config.inc.php`.